# Realtime coredata autosave

Tags: objective-c, core-data, autosave

I have a little statusbar app. It saves when I close the window, it saves when I quit the app but it isn't going to save every time I edit a row in my tableview or I add something to my arraycontroller.
Is there a method to call saveAction at least every "enter" hit or when I confirm an edit?
A save button is not what I'm searching for.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By an 'enter' hit do you mean every time the enter key is pressed when the focus is on the tableview? Also, what did you have in mind on how to confirm an edit without some sort of save button?

Comment: for example: if I have a tableview and I doubleclick on a textcell I'll enter in edit mode and the value will be updated every time I will hit the enter key. In a textview, where the enter key is accepted as a line break, I will confirm the edit simply "taking away" the focus from that textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply set your view controller as the delegate for both the textfield and textview. In an iOS environment you would add the protocol UITextFieldDelegate and UITextViewDelegate to your view controller header file and implement the methods `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and `- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` for the UITextField and UITextView respectively.

As an alternative on a UITextField (iOS), there is a delegate method named `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` which is called whenever the 'enter' key is pressed on a UITextField.

In a Mac OSX environment you would add the appropriate protocol to your view controller header file (for NSTextView add the NSTextDelegate, for NSTextField add the NSControlTextEditingDelegate) and then implement the appropriate methods: `-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification` for an NSTextView and `- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor` for an NSTextField.

You can do any kind of validation you need to in those methods and then do a call to `[myMOC save:&error];` before you return.

Comment: this works great for textfields but not for checkbox. However I can use NSNotification for these controls.

Comment: If those are the basic controls you are looking to save on modify, then I agree, it's easier to just implement a basic notification or KVO method to do the save on a checkbox. If you had a very complicated cell structure with a variety of controls you could simply add calls to that notification method whenever you wanted to invoke a save on a state change which would make it easier to implement/more flexible than a KVO strategy.

Comment: however you should modify your answer because it's incorrect: in cocoa you have ho use `controlTextDidEndEditing` instead of `textFieldDidEndEditing` that is for ios

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I didn't see any tag for cocoa classes, although I suppose it's implied by you stating 'I have a little statusbar app'. I will edit the answer to encompass both iOS and Cocoa text editing paradigms when I get a second.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

1) Create a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to add functionality for autosaving. You can substitute the line `do { try managedObjectContext?.save() } catch { print(error) }` by something like `saveContext()` if you have a global function defined elsewhere. Note that `autosave` is disabled by default.

```
class AutoSaveManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    class var autosave: Bool { return false }
    var autosave: Bool?

    private var previousValue: AnyObject?

    override func willChangeValueForKey(key: String) {
        super.willChangeValueForKey(key)
        if ( autosave == true ) || ( autosave == nil && self.dynamicType.autosave ) {
            previousValue = valueForKey(key)
        }
    }

    override func didChangeValueForKey(key: String) {
        super.didChangeValueForKey(key)
        if ( autosave == true ) || ( autosave == nil && self.dynamicType.autosave ) {
            if "\(previousValue)" != "\(valueForKey(key))" {
                do { try managedObjectContext?.save() } catch { print(error) }
            }
            previousValue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

2) Make all core data objects subclasses of `AutoSaveManagedObject` rather than of `NSManagedObject`. If you want to enable autosaving, you should write something like this:

```
class MyMO: AutoSaveManagedObject {

    override class var autosave: Bool { return true }

    // Your @NSManaged vars here

}
```

3) Now all the instances of `MyMO` have autosave enabled. If you want to disable it for a certain instance, you can always write:

```
let myMO = ... as? MyMO
myMO?.autosave = false
```

Note that the instance's `var autosave` always has higher priority than the `class var autosave`, so you can set `myMO?.autosave = nil` in order to use the default `autosave` setting of the class.

Answer (score -1):

When ever you edit a row within that method write this code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:(autosaveCoreData:) name:nil object:your_tableview_object];
```

-(void)autosaveCoreData:(Event*)event{

```
event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event"      inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

[event setValue:Attribute_Value forKey:@"your atttribute"];
NSError *error;
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

}
  }
}
```

I hope this may solve your problem

Comment: The first line of that code calls a nonexistent method. What notification are you trying to observe? On what object?

Comment: I guess that will compile, but... is it really what you mean to do? This observes every single notification that the object posts. Are you certain it will never post a notification for any other reason? Why not use a notification name?

Comment: When ever editing tableview method is called, it will pass the Notification and perform the function of saving the data.we can certainly use notification name but in this case I'm not sure if we really need it.

Comment: And if it's not a row edit but a checkbox?
However there was another answer here, now there isn't. It was a link to blog.vucica.net/2011/10/autosaving-core-data-managed-object-context.html . What do you think about it?

Comment: There is no need to use NSTimer if you don't want to delay the method. In case of check box use use if-else statement. If check box is checked then perform NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Not using a notification name is almost always an error, especially when you don't have the source code to the class you're observing. A class with unknown source code might post all kinds of notifications for undocumented reasons. Observing with no name will get all of them, even ones you don't want. You really need a notification name in every case where you don't have the source code to the class you're observing, and even in those cases it's an extremely good idea to use the name.